# How to configure apache-airflow with Django project for use of ORM's

Tags: django, airflow, django-orm

I want to configure apache-airflow with the Django project. But I didn't find any proper resources that help me to set up this. Basically, I want to use Django Orm for scheduling tasks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use it on top of airflow backend db? why?

Comment: yes, like in my projects I have used cron job for scheduling some tasks, so now I'm thinking to use airflow

Comment: If you are a beginner my recommendation for you is do not overcomple things. Use Airflow as recommended (as explained in the docs)

Comment: Yes, I'm a beginner and currently exploring apache-airflow, so I came to know that It's helpful for scheduling task like we schedule jobs in corn but It's time-consuming to figure out why certain jobs failed, so airflow provides a WebUI which helps to understand a complete workflow and proper logs with certain to each kind of task. So I'm just exploring things around that if it's possible to use airflow in the Django project so that I'm able to use ORM i.e Django models with airflow. Please helps me to understand airflow concepts properly or if I'm on the wrong way please suggest a better one.

Comment: @ShivamJain I don't know where you are with this now. But anyone who visit this question, I believe this is one good article to read about >>> https://dev.to/jperozo/singer-etl-airflow-django-docker-the-last-frontier-217l